# How can I integrate a custom step function in python accurately (scipy.integrate.quad returning very high error)?

Tags: python, scipy, scientific-computing

I have a custom step function that, when plotted, is like this:[image]

I have modified the datetimes to float values using .timestamp(), and have used scipy.integrate.quad to integrate this. However, the absolute error I get as an output is incredibly high - over the full range of my data (approximately 30x the plot, but in the similar pattern) - I get a integral value of 776197710.7495924 but an error value of 525307969.5046983 which is the same magnitude. When I choose not to use the step function and instead smoothly interpolate over the points using scipy.interp1d and then integrate that function, I get similar figures.

How can I integrate this with less error?

EDIT: I am fully aware of how to just sum the rectangles created by the step function, but I want to understand how I might do this with scipy. Thanks!

Comment: did you try bumping up `limit`?

Answer (score 0):

I normally get good enough results with the [simpsons integration rule](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html#scipy.integrate.simps)  --- [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
x = np.linspace(-3.145, 3.145, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)/x
integrate.simps(y, x)
>> 3.7038704152755586
```

Which is consistent [with the expected result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin(x)%2Fx%20,%20from%20-pi%20to%20pi).

If you are having bad results, maybe your signal is to long and you are accumulating to many approximation errors ?

Comment: @jaromrax if you have all the y and x values for your functions, it does.

Comment: I mean, e.g. - if x axis are values of some measurement (not equidistant in general), then - does this integration works?

Comment: Do you mean if your X is not sampled propperly ? Like sparse x values ? Then you might have reconstruction problems ( See Nyquist Theorem) . But that is independent of the (or any) integration solution. Thus a different issue .It also does not to see the issue with the shown plot.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the ref. to Nyquist. Let us say the x points are equidistant. How your sin(x)/x solves the graph integration?

Comment: You can reconstructed any signal to its original form as long as your sampling rate is 2x higher then the highest frequency of your sample. Then you can just use the reconstructed signal to do the integral. But again : I think this is goign beyond the scope of the question.  If you have more questions on this I think https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ is the place for them.